# Zeta function for Powerful Polynomials over Finite Field

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, riemann-zeta, euler-product

I am currently working on a problem that requires me to get find a simpler expresion for:
$$\sum_{f \in \mathcal{S}_h} \frac{1}{|f|^s} $$

Where $\mathcal{S}_h$ is the set of $h$-full polynomials (i.e. $f \in \mathcal{S}_h$ if the multiplicity of each prime factor of $f$ is $h$ or greater) over a finite field of cardinality $q$ and where $|f|:= q^{\deg(f)}$.

Using Euler's product one can see that:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\sum_{f \in \mathcal{S}_h} \frac{1}{|f|^s} &= \prod_{P \ \text{prime}} \left(1+\frac{1}{|P|^{hs}} + \frac{1}{|P|^{(h+1)s}}+\dots\right)\\
&=\prod_{P \ \text{prime}} \left(1+\frac{1}{|P|^{hs}\left(1-\frac{1}{|P|^s}\right)} \right)\\
&= \prod_{P \ \text{prime}} \left(\frac{1-\frac{1}{|P|^s} + \frac{1}{|P|^{hs}}}{1-\frac{1}{|P|^s}}\right) = \zeta_q(s) \ \prod_{P \ \text{prime}} \left(1-\frac{1}{|P|^s} + \frac{1}{|P|^{hs}} \right)
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

I've thought about how to simplify that last product but I haven't got closer to a cleaner expression. I was expecting to find one similar to that of $h$-free polynomials which is $\frac{\zeta_q(s)}{\zeta_q(hs)}$ but I haven't been able. Any ideas of how to continue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume you mean monic polynomials. If $h=2$ we can write $1-x+x^2=\frac{(1-x^6)(1-x)}{(1-x^2)(1-x^3)}$, but otherwise not much luck. You can always write $\prod\limits_P E\big(\frac{1}{|P|^s}\big)=\prod\limits_{n=1}^\infty E\big(\frac{1}{q^{ns}}\big)^{M(q,n)}$ where the necklace polynomial $M(q,n)=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{d\mid n}\mu\big(\frac{n}{d}\big)q^d$ counts the (monic) irreducibles of degree $n$.